# How can I use a regular expression to accomplish the following?

Tags: regex

The department number is either 5 digits, first digit has to be non-zero, or six digits, with a period and a 0 or 1 following.

So, first example would be 10000, 50050, 99999.
Second, 992000.1, 950000.0.

This is a simple "mask", so no coding is available in the GUI / native format.

Currently, I had `[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,4}` for the first option

Comment: You must have tried _something_

Comment: Currently, I had [1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,4} for the first option.

Comment: I had it built, and it was working, then the second "scenario" popped up.

Comment: In the six digit version, is the first digit allowed to be zero there?

Comment: Five digits, first is non-zero, is `[1-9]\d{4}`, whereas the other one is either `\d{6}\.[01]` or `[1-9]\d{5}\.[01]` depending on whether the first digit is allowed to be zero. Simply concatenate the two with a vertical bar, `|`, and prepend with `^` to signal "start of string here" and a suffix of `$` for "end of string here", giving you either `^[1-9]\d{4}|\d{6}\.[01]$` or `^[1-9]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{5}\.[01]$`

Comment: `{1}` is a no-op. It means "match the previous sub-expression exactly once". The same thing happens without `{1}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\b(?:[1-9][0-9]{4}|[0-9]{6}\.[01])\b
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/bBZKdj/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{4}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{6}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (6 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [01]                     any character of: '0', '1'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much, I probably would not have stumbled on that answer, but I will definitely learn from it.